# Jquery slidedown not working when i click the other button

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, slidedown

I am using the below code(partial code only) for display the div with bounce effect. This is working fine when i click the filter button. Suppose i clicked the add new button the next time filter button not working. Please help me..

```
<td class="fond8" nowrap="nowrap" width="20%">
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn_add" runat="server" Style="padding-left: 10px;" alt="Add New Record"
    ToolTip="Add New Record" Width="35px" ImageUrl="~/Img/IconButton/ibtn_add.png"
    OnClick="imgbtn_add_Click" ClientIDMode="Static" /><span>Add New</span>
    <asp:ImageButton ID="Filter" runat="server" Style="padding-left: 10px;" alt="Add New Record"
    ToolTip="Add New Record" Width="35px" ClientIDMode="Static" ImageUrl="~/Img/IconButton/ibtn_filter.png" /><span>Filter</span>
</td>

     <div id="panel">
                Search By :
     </div>

<script>
        $(function () {
            var $cart = $('#panel');

            alert('entger hgeree');
            $('#<%= Filter.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
                alert('enerer ererererr');
                e.stopPropagation();
                if ($cart.is(":hidden")) {
                    $cart.slideDown("slow", "easeOutBounce");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $cart.slideUp("slow");
                    return false;
                }
            });

        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function () {
            var $cart = $('#panel');
            alert('entger hgeree');
            $('#<%= Filter.ClientID %>').on('click', function (e) {
                alert('enerer ererererr');
                e.stopPropagation();
                if ($cart.is(":hidden")) {
                    $cart.slideDown("slow", "easeOutBounce");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $cart.slideUp("slow");
                    return false;
                }
            });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
$(document).on('click','#<%= Filter.ClientID %>',function (e) {
```

Use event delegation

Comment: Not undersrand your problem :-(

Comment: First time its working fine.this is not working when i click the other button in this page..

Comment: use class instead of id

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation

```
$(document).("click" , '#<%= Filter.ClientID %>' , function (e) {
                alert('enerer ererererr');
                e.stopPropagation();
                if ($cart.is(":hidden")) {
                    $cart.slideDown("slow", "easeOutBounce");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    $cart.slideUp("slow");
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other guys have said you need to use event delegation, just in case you're not sure it means you can add events to elements that have not been created yet :

http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/